# Downloading multiple XML product feeds regularly. Considerations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed

I have a website that is currently fetching and reading 170 feeds ranging from just a few products to tens of thousands. On average they have 3 000 products each. Fetching, reading and update the db accordingly takes in the range of days, even weeks. This is actually not a huge problem since I can spread the job out over the month (they are not updated too frequently).

I think my current solution is not the most optimal though and would like to have some feedback:

1. I use **open-uri** to fetch the feeds, one at a time
2. Then I use **Nokogiri** to parse the feed and loop through all the products
3. Depending on if a product exist or not I create or update the post in the db.

I looked into Feedzirra but it turned out to be more for blog feeds. Are there any other gems or methods I should look into in order to speed things up and make this rather straightforward approach?

The fetching part is usually the faster part so the most I would gain from would be for the actual update of the database. Are there any smart gems or approaches for making multiple updates and creates at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Moving information to the database in large chunks as oppsosed looping around a single sql statement is faster and reduces resource useage on the hosting server see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10560813/723871 the code is for PHP but the technique should translate to ruby.

Something else to consider is  efficiency. If an RSS feed containing say 20 items has had only one new item added since the last time you looked then there is no need to scrape the product pages of the remaining 19 again. Whilst this can be a pain to code it will help turbocharge content retrieval across multiple feeds. A similiar configuration over at the lovelogic.net UK Job scanner watches some 570 feeds daily using this approach.