# When iterating through loops, is it more/less efficient to access a MySQL within loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, web-scraping

I'm writing a PHP script to scrape data from the web. End-result, I want to have all the scraped data tucked and formatted nicely in a mysql database.

But as there are multiple loops and arrays to iterate through within the PHP script, my gut feeling is that for speed and efficiency, it would be best NOT to keep loop-cycling access to the mysql database (inserting data on each go-around of the loops) -- instead, storing the data in temporary arrays within PHP, and then only at the end of the script, dumping the arrays into mysql in one go.

What say ye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, generally being minimal when it comes to the number of querys is performant. But, your script is limited by network io(download speed), not the database. Your script will be asleep most of the time while the os downloads the data. Any queries you issue would be relatively infrequent because of that.

my advice is to just get it working.

Answer (score 5):

you can use Insert into values("1","2","3"),("3","5,"5")

in foreach, you can create an array of values and out of forloop you can implode and insert into mysql.

Lets say,

```
$values = array();
foreach($yourData as $eachData){

// prepare your values here.
$values[] = "('1','2',3')";

}


// out of forloop,
$values = implode(",",$values); 

$query = " insert into `tablename` (field1,field2,field2) values {$values} " ;
```

Cheers

Comment: Technique also doubles up as a workaround for scripting a CSV to mysql table transfer if a webhost has the BULK INSERT command disabled.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, you can insert multiple rows with one query, which is much more optimized than using a separate query for each row. You can add more rows to the query string with a loop, but above all, remember to escape the data!

```
<?php    
$rows = array();
$sql = '
    INSERT INTO `table` (`key`, `data`)
    VALUES ';

$data = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'key1',
        'value' => 'some value'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'key2',
        'value' => 'some value 2'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'key3',
        'value' => 'some value 3'
    ),
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); ++$i)
{
    // Do me a favor and look up PDO.
    $key = mysql_escape_string($data[$i]['key']);
    $row = mysql_escape_string($data[$i]['value']);

    if ($i === 0)
        $sql .= ' (\'' . $key . '\', \'' . $row . '\')';
    else
        $sql .= ', (\'' . $key . '\', \'' . $row . '\')';
}
```

Comment: I used `mysql_escape_string()` as an example here, because there was no actual mysql connection. You should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` in production environments because it escapes the string according to the current character set.